# tensorflow multiply two tensors

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply two tensors together that both have the same shape:

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200], stddev=0.35),
                      name="weights")
weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200], stddev=0.35),
                      name="weights2")


greg = tf.matmul(weights,weights2)


sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.close()
```

Trying this in jupyter notebook, I get this error:

"Shapes (200,) and (?, ?) must have the same rank"

What am I missing?

Comment: From the documentation: "The [`matmul`] inputs must be two-dimensional matrices, with matching inner dimensions, possibly after transposition." Yours aren't. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#matmul

Answer (score 1):

As NPE mentions in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881932/tensorflow-multiply-two-tensors#comment65125284_38881932), the [`tf.matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#matmul) op expects both of its inputs to be two-dimensional tensors, but your arguments `weights` and `weights2` are one-dimensional tensors.

If you want to compute the inner product of these two tensors, you need to reshape them to be 200-by-1 and 1-by-200 matrices, using (e.g.) [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) as follows:

```
greg = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(weights, [1, 200]), tf.reshape(weights2, [200, 1]))
```